# How to get the result from an array?

Tags: angular

I have such JSON:

```
{
  "count": 1,
    "rows": [
      {
        "hour_id": 1,
        "report_date": "2019-10-22",
        "teams_id": 5,
        "team": {
          "team_id": 5,
          "full_name": "trytrys",
          "is_active": true,
          "masters": [
            {
              "master_id": 11,
              "full_name": "sf",
              "comment": "gff",
              "date_work": "2019-06-22",
              "teams_id": 5
            },
            {
              "master_id": 10,
              "full_name": "dgdf",
              "comment": "hjgj",
              "date_work": "2019-10-05",
              "teams_id": 5
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

And I need to get data from the masters from this array. To be able to further find the maximum field `date_work`. How can get data on the masters?

ts:

```
  private load() {
    const params = {
      search: this.search,
      pageSize: this.pageSize,
      page: this.page
    };
    this.loading = true;
    this.isActive = false;
    this._homeService.fetch(this.report_date, params).subscribe(repHours => {
      this.loading = false;
      this.isActive = true;
      this.repHours = repHours.rows;
      this.totalItems = repHours.count;
    }, error => {
      this.loading = false;
      this.isActive = true;
      console.log(error)
    })
  }
```

html:

```
<div *ngFor="let repHour of repHours">
    {{repHour.team.masters.date_work}}
</div>
```

Comment: response.masters.map(master => console.log(master.date_work))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `masters` is in array format so In order to access inner property you need to add nested `*ngFor`, like below -

```
<div *ngFor="let repHour of repHours">
    <div *ngFor="let masters of repHour?.team?.masters">{{masters?.date_work}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just use map to loop, example: `JSONDATA.rows.map(row => row.team.masters.map(master => console.log(master.date_work)));`

check it out: https://jsfiddle.net/35j4th89/3/

Answer (score 0):

```
new Date(Math.max.apply(null, a.rows.team.masters.map(function(e) {
         return new Date(e.date_works);
})));
```

This way you can get Max date.